# Python - The "input()" function doesn't get executed

Tags: python, input

I wrote this code in Python3:

```
for _ in range(2):
    inputs = input()
    print(inputs)
```

It works fine when I provide the input values one by one.
It also works when the input values are copied and pasted as in [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwjuc.png) and the [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1kcU.png) is printed in the terminal.

However, when the input is copied and pasted as in [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Wl3.png), it just doesn't print the last line and expects the user to press enter (or to add more characters and then press enter) to finish the code: [Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMMsv.png)

What is going on?

Why is this happening and how can I solve it when some other program or a user gives the input that way?

Comment: Please update to remove the images and paste proper text.

Comment: there is not new line after the second input

Comment: You need to copy a second new line before pasting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

There is no `new line` after the second input please provide `new line` (by hitting `enter`) .

After **insert 1 10** there is **no** `new line` and `input` method is waiting for user to provide a `new line` so it will stop reading and return string as output.